# xPath: From parent node, descend to sub-sub-sub child node that matches condition?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm trying to write a `xpath` that gets the text from `"I want to get this text snippet"` below.

```
<root>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h2>Issuer</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> Name </td>
          <td class="text-right"> I want to get this text snippet </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</root>
```

So far I have this:

```
//h2["Issuer"]/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div//td["Name"]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

There are two parts to this line at the moment:

1. `//h2["Issuer"]/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div` which takes us to `<div class="table-responsive">`.
2. `//td["Name"]/following-sibling::td/text()` which takes us to the text snippet target in its `<td>` block.

Both parts are important because there are multiple places in the real webpage source code where `<td> Name </td>` can be found. So the first part determines where in the overall structure to start looking.

Is my usage of `//` leading the second part the correct way to descend to any child node that matches the condition? I ask this because I can't find a match.

Comment: Are you sure the spaces in `" Name "` are not relevant?

Comment: @alexe's answer combined with the concept that `//` can be applied within an XPath expression to descend *at that point* (not starting over from the root)  should be all you need to answer your question.   Do you still have an open issue?

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks, that resolves the question! I hadn't accepted the answer yet because my script isn't working yet – thereby having no way of verifying the answer. But given that the assumptions are now clear I will be able to accept the answer and continue debugging.

Comment: Np, just wasn't sure if the continued edits to the question were an attempt to say something still was unanswered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct, just add a text check:

```
//td[normalize-space(.) = "Name"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```